# ImportError: No module named cv2 in caffe installed in ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, opencv, importerror, caffe

I installed `caffe` from [this site](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-Installation-Guide) on Ubuntu 16.04. python 2.7 is default and there is python 3.5.2 on system,too. I installed `apollocaffe` too. When I was trying to run my code, an error occured:

`ImportError: No module named cv2`

I did execute this code: `sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev` as in installation guide is said.

and in `Makefile.config` I uncommented the line about `python3`.
I viewed the `dist-packages` in python3.5 and it is empty.

what should I do??? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you import cv2 in python?

Comment: @malreddysid  No I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for my case:

> pip install opencv-python

and now

> import cv2

works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed opencv2? then did you import it as cv2?

Comment: I did the installation guide. and this "sudo apt-get install -y libopencv-dev" code is for installing opencv 2.4 . but when I import it to python error occures.